# State wages not from state where I was living

Tags: united-states, income-tax, income-tax-refund, turbotax

In my W-2 I have State wages from MA and corresponding state taxes were withdrew from my salary. But I lived actually in other state.

When I completed taxes in turbotax, I thought it should recalculate and I should get refund from MA and pay RI state taxes instead.

But turbotax think that I should pay MA taxes, not RI.

Just want to check if it's correct before submitting.

Comment: Did you download the RI and MA modules for TurboTax.?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep, what do you mean? I use online version.

Comment: You will have to tell turbo tax that you are not a resident of MA, but you are a resident of RI. How the two states handle this depends on the reciprocity agreements they have. In some cases it is important where you live, in other cases it depends on where you work.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep, yes, I specified that I was RI resident and was surprised that it calculated 0$ for RI and big MA amount. I thought you pay taxes where you live, related question: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29063/do-i-pay-taxes-where-i-live-or-where-i-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I completed taxes in turbotax, I thought it should recalculate
>   and I should get refund from MA and pay RI state taxes instead.
>
> But turbotax think that I should pay MA taxes, not RI.

Since you live in Rhode Island I went to the RI Government website:

[Frequently Asked Questions Regarding 2011 Rhode Island Personal Income 
Tax Withholding and Revised Personal Income Tax Rates](http://www.tax.ri.gov/info/2011%20Withholding%20FAQs.pdf)

> **7. I am a Rhode Island resident, but I work in another state.  Is my employer required to withhold Rhode Island income tax from my wages?**
>
> An employee who is a resident of Rhode Island is subject to Rhode
>   Island withholding for wages earned in Rhode Island.  If a Rhode
>   Island resident works in another state, such as Massachusetts or
>   Connecticut, the wages will be taxed in the state where the wages are
>   earned.  The Rhode Island resident may claim a credit for income tax
>   paid to the other state on the RI-1040 resident  income tax return.

So If the State of Massachusetts Taxes are greater than the taxes that RI was expecting. Then when RI credits you for what you paid MA then the Income tax you should pay RI will be zero.

Of course all this depends on other income you may have that isn't MA income. And is income tax only.